# How do I require authentication for POST requests but allow unathenticated use for GET requests on my token-secured API?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I have REST API and I want a certain route on which requests are `GET` to be public, but I want `POST` request to require a token.

Example:

```
// config/packages/security.yaml

security:
    # ...
    firewalls:
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/v1/
            // here I want to allow public GET
            // but want to disallow POST without a token
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\TokenAuthenticator
```

I have a standard `TokenAuthenticator` class, in charge of authenticating users.

How can I configure Symfony security so that `POST` requests require authorization, but `GET` requests can be performed by unauthenticated (anonymous) users?

Comment: Andrei, did the answer below helped you? Any feedback?

Answer (score 2):

This can be very succinctly achieved with access control rules:

E.g.:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/v1, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: [GET] }
        - { path: ^/api/v1, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, methods: [POST] }
```

With this, POST requests to `api/v1` will require the user to have been authenticated and ave a `ROLE_ADMIN` assigned, but `GET` requests to the same path will be allowed for unauthenticated users.